# Is it okay to use "very Good morning" instead of 'Good morning'

Tags: grammaticality, greetings

while on cold call, is it okay to wish "a very good morning" instead of 'good morning', followed by your name and introduction? Or is it that we may wish "a very Good morning" to only those who are known to us?
in professional cold calling, shall we just stick to 'good morning"?

Answer (score 2):

Peter is right - although it should really be "A very good morning *to you…*"; otherwise, what he said applies in any other context.

In the context of cold calling it's not a question of grammar. "Good morning" might be formally polite enough to overcome the fact that the caller is intruding into the callee's day…

Anything more, whether it be "A very good morning to you…" or "How are you?" or *anything* but that basic "good morning" or the - usually omitted - "Is this a convenient time for me to call you?" is at best patronising.

If you must cold call, please don't try to deceive people into thinking of you as a friend.

Comment: Let's also remember that the doyen of English usage, the BBC is very sure it's wholly acceptable to use 'Morning…' by itself…

Answer (score 1):

> A very good morning

is an acceptable salutation [here](http://www.wipo.int/edocs/mdocs/mdocs/en/who_wipo_wto_ip_med_ge_13/who_wipo_wto_ip_med_ge_13_openingremarks.pdf), it might be considered similar to

> [Top 'o the mornin'](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=top%20o'%20the%20mornin'%20to%20ya)

where both would usually be said in a happy voice with a big smile.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically it may be wrong, but what the one who says that phrase feels and wishes to express is something that is beyond just what a simple 'Good Morning' conveys. In any formal sentences or conversations, it is best to avoid it. But for someone special to you, if it conveys atleast some of the feelings that you express, it is worth it.

Answer (score -1):

some person are there who want to underestimate the caller or the sender by using such words like very or very very good morning ... my dear.. and dear etc. I am always getting provoked on hearing or seeing such things as their intention is nothing but to underestimate our value as if they are on top position than me.

actually I am ignoring such person to meet and even to talk. A same bad behavior is the  tapping the shoulder on wishing or shaking hands as if he is better than us.

Answer (score -2):

In this sentence, 'Very good morning' what does 'very' measures to? I do not see any reason to add very. Just, Good Morning is a complete phrase.

Comment: "Good morning" is a wish for someone to *have* a good morning. "Very" intensifies "good". A "very good" morning is considerably better than one that is merely "good".

Answer (score -2):

My understanding is that Good Morning is a standard set phrase. As such you aren't permitted to dilute it by adding  extra qualifiers like, very and very very before  Good Morning.